# Tcl: K trick / unsharing objects also for embracing a list?

Tags: tcl

What I'm trying to do is to put an additional level of braces around a list:

```
set l [list $l]
```

For operations of the type

```
set someVar [someFunc $someVar]
```

it is recommended (https://stackoverflow.com/a/67318915/3852630, https://stackoverflow.com/a/64117854/3852630, https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/K) to use

```
set someVar [someFunc $someVar[set someVar {}]]
```

instead which is known to drastically improve performance.

Two questions:

- Would this also apply to `list`, so should I use this for my specific problem?:

```
set l [list $l[set l {}]]
```

- Is there another efficient way to add an additional level of braces?

Thanks for your help!

---

Edit: corrected error pointed out by Chris Heithoff

Comment: You don't need the variable-take tricks in this case; you're not updating the value itself, but rather just wrapping it.

Comment: @DonalFellows: Thanks. But isn't the wrapping totally modifying the list, from multiple elements to a single one? Why is wrapping a different case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an explanation of why you don't need the K trick.

Tcl's values are in general reference counted compound values that have a guaranteed serialization to a string; this is normally concealed information but it's how things really work. In fact, some of our strings also have complicated internal representations some of the time, making Tcl's strings a lot faster than those in C, C++, or Java most of the time.

To go with this is a model where you have to copy a value to modify it. But we don't actually do that; it's rather slow if you have to copy things all the time! Instead, we only take a copy when we're writing to a *shared* value; the value is shallow deduplicated, the updates are applied to the new copy, and then that's used where it should be (e.g., written back to the variable). This is done in a recursive fashion as required, so that the right thing happens when you do a modification deep inside a nested list or dictionary.

When are values shared? Well, there are a few places that can hold references (e.g., lists and dicts) but the key ones here are:

1. Variables. (Duh! This is a really obvious one!)
2. The Tcl execution stack. This is where Tcl holds the results of substitutions, variable reads, and commands until it can dispatch to the command it is about to call next. *In theory* an alternate execution mechanism could be used, but you'd still have to hold the references for the same amount of time to get the execution model right.

So, what happens in the classic case for K? Well, you start by doing `set x [linsert $x 0 a]` which (ignoring bytecoding) will do:

1. Push `set`.
2. Push `x`.
3. Push `linsert`
4. Push the value read from `x`. (Keep an eye on this: it now has *two* references, one from the variable and one from the stack)
5. Push `0`
6. Push `a`
7. Invoke (of `linsert`) consuming 4 values from the stack (steps 3–6) and pushing the result. The value references to the arguments are only dropped after the command implementation returns, ensuring that arguments don't disappear from under the command's feet.
8. Invoke (of `set`) consuming 3 values from the stack (steps 1, 2 and 7).

The implementation of `linsert` can do an in-place edit of the list if the value is unshared, but as noted in step 4 the value is naturally shared, so it must be deduplicated, making this necessarily an expensive operation.

The classic K trick is this:

```
proc K {x y} {return $x};  # This is the K combinator

set x [linsert [K $x [set x DUMMY]] 0 a]
```

That effectively does a take-from-variable (leaving an arbitrary value behind). You're using an optimised version of that (which depends on bytecode trickery and a semantic optimisation in the guts of the string concatenation implementation).

But why don't we need it for `set x [list $x]`? Well, in that case we're not updating the *value,* we're just encapsulating it in a list wrapper value and then updating the *variable*. Values are not variables. You can get the exact value that was previously in there with `lindex $x 0`; confirm this for yourself with `tcl::unsupported::representation`, whose output includes where values are actually stored in memory (as well as both reference count and type info). It's a neat debugging tool, though sometimes quite surprising!

---

[EDIT]: To illustrate what I meant, here's a little interactive session. Pay particular attention to the `object pointer`; that's the memory address of the `Tcl_Obj` structure and is effectively the true identity of the value. (This is normally strictly ignored in Tcl; values are not supposed to have identity as such, as that's a concept that is reserved for named entities like variables. With being named comes the idea that things can be modified.)

```
% set x "a b c"
a b c
% tcl::unsupported::representation $x
value is a pure string with a refcount of 4, object pointer at 0x7ff2eba275b0, string representation "a b c"
% set x [list $x]
{a b c}
% tcl::unsupported::representation $x
value is a list with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0x7ff2eba26ec0, internal representation 0x7ff2eb02f290:0x0, string representation "{a b c}"
% tcl::unsupported::representation [lindex $x 0]
value is a pure string with a refcount of 4, object pointer at 0x7ff2eba275b0, string representation "a b c"
% set x [linsert $x 0 d]
d {a b c}
% tcl::unsupported::representation $x
value is a list with a refcount of 2, object pointer at 0x7ff2eba2b930, internal representation 0x7ff2eb02d090:0x0, string representation "d {a b c}"
```

As you can see, the *original* value is still inside the list; it's not been altered in any way.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Very clear and helpful description of the general mechanism, but I'm still not sure I understand the special case (particularly the remark "encapsulating it in a list wrapper value"), but I will need some time to explore it further as you suggested. So I'll remove the (modified) K trick from the `list` code and accept this as the right answer.

Comment: It's not a special case. It's that it is a case that _uses_ the value instead of _modifing_ the value.

Comment: Also, note that the list implementation might decide that taking a copy is more efficient in some cases anyway. It's very much allowed to do that.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that makes it more clear for me.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that should work.   `list` is just another possible thing to substitute into `someFunc` in the recommendation for K.

Your specific example for list isn't quite right though.

```
set l [list $l[set $l {}]]
```

..you want to assign an empty string to the variable name `l`, not the value of `$l` to actually benefit.
Do this instead:

```
set l [list $l[set l {}]]
```

Comment: Thanks, you're right, I corrected my post.