# "Compact" query strings for prepared-statement cache?

Tags: sqlite, tcl

If SQL queries are stored in Tcl variables declared across multiple lines to keep them readable, using:

```
set ::SQL::QueryName {
}
```

and executed using

```
db eval $::SQL::QueryName
```

should something be done to the query strings since they will be the keys in the prepared-statements cache?

For example, ending each line with the line-continuation character `\`, build with `append` statements, or running some type of mapping on them to make a single line with no unnecesary spaces?

Hadn't thought about it before because caching is sort of automatic in Tcl SQLite.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you any problems ?

Comment: The hash table code doesn't care if a string has newlines in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't bother doing clever stuff like that; statement caching is usually totally happy as an automatic thing that happens behind the scenes. Just write the SQL directly as program literals (*the* obvious first option!) and it should all work out fine.

One principle of Tcl is that we try to make obvious-looking code be fast code, with as few contortions as possible (as this makes it easier for users to adopt and adapt). The only real common rules we have for fast code are "put things in procedures" and "put braces round expressions". There are a few other tricks (such as the now-very-inaccurately-named K trick), but you don't normally need them. A consequence of this attitude is that caches are transparent and in fact pretty ubiquitous; they're the job of C extensions to worry about, not normal user code.

In short, don't sweat it. Seriously.

Comment: Thank you. Your reference to the K trick made me curious and, whilst looking it up, found these SO answers (of yours) on the topic and figured it might save someone a few minutes to include them here.  [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70974121/tcl-k-trick-unsharing-objects-also-for-embracing-a-list)  and [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67312596/accelerate-tcl-eval) and [tcl wiki](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/K). Mr. Nadkarni's text p.616 24.2.3 Perfomance hints includes some related information.

Answer (score 1):

You've asked a few questions about efficiency in areas that make me think you'd benefit from an understanding of the way Tcl values are generally handled.  I'm not familiar with the details of sqlite's query caching, but it could be implemented in this way (I've done that for various db drivers, caching db prepared statements in objtype intreps).  At other times I've just put it in a dictionary with the SQL string as the key.  In that case, it would be insignificantly slower to have a longer string (more bytes to hash), but the Tcl hash function is *very* fast, I never worry about it.  If stored as the intrep, the string length wouldn't matter at all - Tcl would just hand back the prepared statement pointer for that Tcl_Obj.

So I've cookied up a toy example of a custom Tcl_ObjType that implements a matrix - the string representation is a table of numbers separated by whitespace with rows separated by newlines.  Internally the c code operates on a struct storing the dimensions and an array of doubles with the data:

```c
package require jitc 0.5.3

namespace eval ::matrix {
    namespace export *
    namespace ensemble create -prefixes no -map {
        mul         mul
        set         _set
        rows        rows
        cols        cols
        transpose   transpose
    }

    # Arrange for GDB to be able to find the code
    set dbg     /tmp/matrix
    file mkdir $dbg
    file delete {*}[glob -nocomplain -type f [file join $dbg *]]

    set cdef [list debug $dbg {*}{
        options     {-Wall -Werror -g}
        filter      {jitc::re2c -W --case-ranges --no-debug-info}
        code {
            #include <stdlib.h>
            #include <string.h>

            struct matrix {
                int     rows;
                int     cols;
                double* data;
            };

            static struct matrix* matrix_alloc(int rows, int cols)
            {
                struct matrix*  m = (struct matrix*)ckalloc(sizeof(struct matrix));
                m->rows = rows;
                m->cols = cols;
                m->data = (double*)ckalloc(sizeof(double)*rows*cols);
                return m;
            }

            static void matrix_free(struct matrix* m)
            {
                ckfree(m->data);
                ckfree(m);
            }


            /* Registry of all the Tcl_Obj's that have our internal representation.
             * We need this because we can be unloaded, and have to update all the
             * Tcl_Obj's whose ObjType handlers point to us (by ensuring that their
             * string rep is valid, and then freeing the internal rep, leaving them
             * as pure strings).
             */
            static Tcl_HashTable    my_intreps;

            static void register_intrep(Tcl_Obj* obj)
            {
                int             isnew;
                Tcl_HashEntry*  he = Tcl_CreateHashEntry(&my_intreps, obj, &isnew);
                if (!isnew) Tcl_Panic("register_intrep: obj already registered");
            }

            static void forget_intrep(Tcl_Obj* obj)
            {
                Tcl_HashEntry*  he = Tcl_FindHashEntry(&my_intreps, obj);
                if (!he) Tcl_Panic("forget_intrep: obj not registered");
                Tcl_DeleteHashEntry(he);
            }


            static void objtype_matrix_free(Tcl_Obj* obj);
            static void objtype_matrix_dup(Tcl_Obj* src, Tcl_Obj* dst);
            static void objtype_matrix_update_stringrep(Tcl_Obj* obj);

            static Tcl_ObjType objtype_matrix = {
                .name             = "matrix",
                .freeIntRepProc   = objtype_matrix_free,
                .dupIntRepProc    = objtype_matrix_dup,
                .updateStringProc = objtype_matrix_update_stringrep
            };

            static void objtype_matrix_free(Tcl_Obj* obj)
            {
                Tcl_ObjInternalRep*     ir = Tcl_FetchInternalRep(obj, &objtype_matrix);
                struct matrix*          m = (struct matrix*)ir->twoPtrValue.ptr1;
                forget_intrep(obj);
                matrix_free(m);
            }

            static void objtype_matrix_dup(Tcl_Obj* src, Tcl_Obj* dst)
            {
                Tcl_ObjInternalRep*     ir = Tcl_FetchInternalRep(src, &objtype_matrix);
                struct matrix*          m = (struct matrix*)ir->twoPtrValue.ptr1;
                struct matrix*          n = matrix_alloc(m->rows, m->cols);
                memcpy(n->data, m->data, sizeof(double)*m->rows*m->cols);
                Tcl_StoreInternalRep(dst, &objtype_matrix, (Tcl_ObjInternalRep*)n);
                register_intrep(dst);
            }

            static void objtype_matrix_update_stringrep(Tcl_Obj* obj)
            {
                Tcl_ObjInternalRep*     ir = Tcl_FetchInternalRep(obj, &objtype_matrix);
                struct matrix*          m = (struct matrix*)ir->twoPtrValue.ptr1;
                Tcl_DString             ds;

                Tcl_DStringInit(&ds);

                Tcl_Obj**       vals = ckalloc(sizeof(Tcl_Obj*) * m->rows * m->cols);
                memset(vals, 0, sizeof(Tcl_Obj*) * m->rows * m->cols);

                // Pretty print the matrix, right-aligning column values
                int         col_max[m->cols];
                memset(col_max, 0, sizeof(col_max));

                for (int r=0; r < m->rows; r++) {
                    for (int c=0; c < m->cols; c++) {
                        Tcl_Obj*    val = Tcl_ObjPrintf("%g", m->data[r*m->cols+c]);
                        int         l;
                        Tcl_GetStringFromObj(val, &l);
                        replace_tclobj(&vals[r*m->cols+c], val);
                        if (l > col_max[c]) col_max[c] = l;
                    }
                }

                for (int r=0; r < m->rows; r++) {
                    for (int c=0; c < m->cols; c++) {
                        Tcl_Obj*    val = vals[r*m->cols+c];
                        int         l;
                        const char* str = Tcl_GetStringFromObj(val, &l);
                        for (int pad=0; pad<col_max[c]-l; pad++) Tcl_DStringAppend(&ds, " ", 1);
                        Tcl_DStringAppend(&ds, str, l);
                        Tcl_DStringAppend(&ds, c == m->cols-1 ? "\n" : " ", 1);
                    }
                }

                // Trim last newline
                Tcl_DStringSetLength(&ds, Tcl_DStringLength(&ds)-1);

                // Update obj's string rep
                Tcl_InitStringRep(obj, Tcl_DStringValue(&ds), Tcl_DStringLength(&ds));

                for (int i=0; i < m->rows * m->cols; i++)
                    replace_tclobj(&vals[i], NULL);

                ckfree(vals);
                Tcl_DStringFree(&ds);
            }


            int init(Tcl_Interp* interp)
            {
                Tcl_InitHashTable(&my_intreps, TCL_ONE_WORD_KEYS);
                return TCL_OK;
            }


            void release(Tcl_Interp* interp)
            {
                /* Iterate through the intrep registry by pulling a single
                 * entry at a time and restarting the search until none remain.
                 * We have to do this because freeing the intrep could change
                 * other Tcl_Objs refcounts, which could affect other entries in
                 * this registry.
                 */
                Tcl_HashSearch  search;
                Tcl_HashEntry*  he;
                while ((he = Tcl_FirstHashEntry(&my_intreps, &search))) {
                    Tcl_Obj* obj = (Tcl_Obj*)Tcl_GetHashKey(&my_intreps, he);
                    Tcl_GetString(obj);         // Ensure that we have a valid string rep
                    Tcl_FreeInternalRep(obj);   // Ensure that we don't point at our objtype handlers
                }
                Tcl_DeleteHashTable(&my_intreps);
            }


            static int get_matrix_from_obj(Tcl_Interp* interp, Tcl_Obj* obj, struct matrix** m)
            {
                int                 code = TCL_OK;
                Tcl_ObjInternalRep* ir = Tcl_FetchInternalRep(obj, &objtype_matrix);
                struct matrix*      newm = NULL;

                if (!ir) {
                    const char*     str = Tcl_GetString(obj);
                    const char*     YYCURSOR;
                    const char*     YYMARKER;
                    int             cols = -1, done = 0, r, c;
                    /*!stags:re2c format = "const char* @@;"; */

                    /*!rules:re2c:common
                        re2c:define:YYCTYPE  = char;
                        re2c:yyfill:enable   = 0;
                        re2c:tags            = 1;

                        end     = [ \t\n]* "\x00";
                        eol     = [ \t]*   "\n";
                        ws      = [ \t];
                        digit   = [0-9];
                        sign    = "+" | "-";
                        exp     = 'e' sign? digit+;
                        int     = sign? digit+;
                        float
                            = sign? digit* "." digit+ exp?
                            | sign? digit+ exp;
                        num     = int | float;
                    */

                    // Eat leading whitespace - may include newlines before the first row
                    while (str[0] == ' ' || str[0] == '\t' || str[0] == '\n') str++;
                    YYCURSOR = str;

                    // Lazy: parse twice - first to get (and verify) the dimensions
                    for (r=0; !done; r++) {
                        for (c=0; !done; c++) {
                            /*!re2c
                            !use:common;

                            ws* num eol  {         c++; break;    }
                            ws* num end  { done=1; c++; break;    }
                            ws* num ws+  {              continue; }

                            *    { THROW_ERROR_LABEL(finally, code, "invalid matrix format"); }

                            */
                        }

                        // Ensure that each row has the same number of columns
                        if (r == 0)         cols = c;
                        else if (c != cols) THROW_ERROR_LABEL(finally, code, "invalid matrix format");
                    }

                    newm = matrix_alloc(r, cols);

                    // Second pass: fill in the data
                    YYCURSOR = str;
                    for (r=0, done=0; !done; r++) {
                        for (c=0; !done; c++) {
                            const char*     v;
                            /*!re2c
                            !use:common;

                            ws* @v num eol  { newm->data[r*cols+c] = strtod(v, NULL);         c++; break;    }
                            ws* @v num end  { newm->data[r*cols+c] = strtod(v, NULL); done=1; c++; break;    }
                            ws* @v num ws+  { newm->data[r*cols+c] = strtod(v, NULL);              continue; }

                            *    { THROW_ERROR_LABEL(finally, code, "invalid matrix format"); }

                            */
                        }
                    }

                    Tcl_StoreInternalRep(obj, &objtype_matrix, &(Tcl_ObjInternalRep){
                        .twoPtrValue.ptr1 = newm
                    });
                    newm = NULL;    // Hand ownership to the intrep
                    register_intrep(obj);
                    ir = Tcl_FetchInternalRep(obj, &objtype_matrix);
                }

                *m = (struct matrix*)ir->twoPtrValue.ptr1;

            finally:
                if (newm) matrix_free(newm);
                return code;
            }


            static Tcl_Obj* new_matrix_obj(struct matrix* m)
            {
                Tcl_Obj*    obj = Tcl_NewObj();
                Tcl_StoreInternalRep(obj, &objtype_matrix, &(Tcl_ObjInternalRep){
                    .twoPtrValue.ptr1 = m
                });
                Tcl_InvalidateStringRep(obj);
                register_intrep(obj);
                return obj;
            }


            static void set_identity(struct matrix* m, int size)
            {
                for (int r=0; r<size; r++)
                    for (int c=0; c<size; c++)
                        m->data[r*size+c] = r == c ? 1 : 0;
            }


            int mul(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp* interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj*const objv[])
            {
                int             code = TCL_OK;
                int             size;
                struct matrix*  out = NULL;
                struct matrix*  tmp = NULL;

                if (objc == 1) THROW_ERROR_LABEL(finally, code, "Need at least one matrix");

                // To keep this example simple, we require that all matrices be square and of the same size
                for (int i=objc-1; i>0; i--) {
                    struct matrix*  m = NULL;
                    TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, get_matrix_from_obj(interp, objv[i], &m));
                    if (i == objc-1) size = m->cols;
                    if (m->cols != size) THROW_ERROR_LABEL(finally, code, "Matrix sizes don't match");
                    if (m->rows != size) THROW_ERROR_LABEL(finally, code, "Matrix sizes don't match");
                }

                out = matrix_alloc(size, size);
                tmp = matrix_alloc(size, size);
                set_identity(out, size);

                for (int i=objc-1; i>0; i--) {
                    struct matrix*  m = NULL;
                    TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, get_matrix_from_obj(interp, objv[i], &m));
                    memcpy(tmp->data, out->data, sizeof(double)*size*size);
                    for (int c=0; c<size; c++) {
                        for (int r=0; r<size; r++) {
                            double      val = 0;
                            for (int k=0; k<size; k++)
                                val += out->data[k*size+c] * m->data[r*size+k];
                            tmp->data[r*size+c] = val;
                        }
                    }

                    memcpy(out->data, tmp->data, sizeof(double)*size*size);
                }

                Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, new_matrix_obj(out));
                out = NULL; // Hand ownership to the result

            finally:
                if (out) matrix_free(out);
                if (tmp) matrix_free(tmp);
                return code;
            }


            int _set(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp* interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj*const objv[])
            {
                int             code = TCL_OK;
                struct matrix*  m;
                int             r, c;
                double          val;
                Tcl_Obj*        matrixobj = NULL;
                Tcl_Obj*        orig_matrixobj = NULL;
                Tcl_Obj*        res = NULL;

                enum {A_cmd, A_MATRIX, A_ROW, A_COL, A_VAL, A_objc};
                CHECK_ARGS_LABEL(finally, code, "matrixvar row col val");

                // Retrieve the value from the variable, duplicate if it is shared
                matrixobj = orig_matrixobj = Tcl_ObjGetVar2(interp, objv[A_MATRIX], NULL, TCL_LEAVE_ERR_MSG);
                if (matrixobj == NULL) {
                    code = TCL_ERROR;
                    goto finally;
                }

                if (Tcl_IsShared(matrixobj))
                    replace_tclobj(&matrixobj, Tcl_DuplicateObj(matrixobj));

                TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, get_matrix_from_obj(interp, matrixobj, &m));
                TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, Tcl_GetIntFromObj(interp, objv[A_ROW], &r));
                TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, Tcl_GetIntFromObj(interp, objv[A_COL], &c));
                TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, Tcl_GetDoubleFromObj(interp, objv[A_VAL], &val));

                if (r < 0 || r >= m->rows) THROW_ERROR_LABEL(finally, code, "row out of range");
                if (c < 0 || c >= m->cols) THROW_ERROR_LABEL(finally, code, "col out of range");

                m->data[r*m->cols+c] = val;
                Tcl_InvalidateStringRep(matrixobj); // We've changed our intrep, so drop the out-of-date string rep

                // Put the changed value back into the variable (ensure that write traces fire)
                res = Tcl_ObjSetVar2(interp, objv[A_MATRIX], NULL, matrixobj, TCL_LEAVE_ERR_MSG);
                if (res == NULL) {
                    code = TCL_ERROR;
                    goto finally;
                }

                // Return the value in the variable (possibly changed by write traces)
                Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, res);

            finally:
                if (matrixobj != orig_matrixobj) replace_tclobj(&matrixobj, NULL);
                return code;
            }


            int rows(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp* interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj*const objv[])
            {
                int             code = TCL_OK;
                struct matrix*  m;

                enum {A_cmd, A_MATRIX, A_objc};
                CHECK_ARGS_LABEL(finally, code, "matrix");

                TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, get_matrix_from_obj(interp, objv[A_MATRIX], &m));
                Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewIntObj(m->rows));

            finally:
                return code;
            }


            int cols(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp* interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj*const objv[])
            {
                int             code = TCL_OK;
                struct matrix*  m;

                enum {A_cmd, A_MATRIX, A_objc};
                CHECK_ARGS_LABEL(finally, code, "matrix");

                TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, get_matrix_from_obj(interp, objv[A_MATRIX], &m));
                Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, Tcl_NewIntObj(m->cols));

            finally:
                return code;
            }


            int transpose(ClientData cdata, Tcl_Interp* interp, int objc, Tcl_Obj*const objv[])
            {
                int             code = TCL_OK;
                struct matrix*  m;
                struct matrix*  out = NULL;

                enum {A_cmd, A_MATRIX, A_objc};
                CHECK_ARGS_LABEL(finally, code, "matrix");

                TEST_OK_LABEL(finally, code, get_matrix_from_obj(interp, objv[A_MATRIX], &m));
                out = matrix_alloc(m->cols, m->rows);
                for (int r=0; r<m->rows; r++)
                    for (int c=0; c<m->cols; c++)
                        out->data[c*m->rows+r] = m->data[r*m->cols+c];

                Tcl_SetObjResult(interp, new_matrix_obj(out));
                out = NULL; // Hand ownership to the result

            finally:
                if (out) matrix_free(out);
                return code;
            }
        }
    }]

    foreach cmd {mul _set rows cols transpose} {
        jitc::bind [namespace current]::$cmd $cdef $cmd
    }
}

set A {
     1  2  3   4
     5  6  7   8
     9 10 11  12
    13 14 15 1e6
}

set B {
    1 0 0 0
    0 0 1 0
    0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 1
}

puts "A before: [tcl::unsupported::representation $A]"

set C [matrix mul $A $B]

puts "A after: [tcl::unsupported::representation $A]"
puts "C after: [tcl::unsupported::representation $C]"

puts "C = BA:\n$C"

puts "C, after puts: [tcl::unsupported::representation $C]"

matrix set C 0 0 42

puts "C, after set: [tcl::unsupported::representation $C]"

puts "Transpose of C:\n[matrix transpose $C]"

puts "time get dimensions of C ([matrix cols $C], [matrix rows $C]): [timerate {
    matrix cols $C
    matrix rows $C
}]"
```

To run it you'll need a recent Tcl 8.7 (new enough to have the TIP445 interface for ObjTypes), and [jitc](https://github.com/cyanogilvie/jitc) (just used here to make it a self-contained example without needing a build system).

Working through this code (together with the man pages for Tcl_RegisterObjType, Tcl_NewObj) and considering:

- when the string representing the matrix is parsed
- when a new string is generated
- how the commands that work with the matrix values access the efficient internal c representation
- when the values are freed and what is holding a reference to them at each point in the example (hint - some are literal objects referred to by the source code)

will, I think, prove enlightening.

`tcl::unsupported::representation` is, as the name suggests, not a supported part of the Tcl API, but is useful to probe the state of a Tcl value (Tcl_Obj instance).  It reports the reference count, the Tcl_ObjType (what it was last used as), and whether it has a string representation.  Note that the refcount reported by `tcl::unsupported::representation` will always include one reference for the arg list of the `tcl::unsupported::representation` command itself.  So if it reports a refcount of 2, that value (likely living in a variable) would have a refcount of 1 when it wasn't being looked at by `tcl::unsupported::representation`.

This isn't exactly how I'd do things if I actually wanted a linear algebra library - I've optimised this example for clarity around the dynamics of Tcl_Obj types.  I picked a matrix to have a non-trivial amount of work to do to parse the string rep and regenerate a pretty-printed one.  If I did this for real I'd probably re-use the Tcl list and number parsers, here it's manual to emphasise the conversion to and from strings.

Comment: Thank you for the example and explanation.